# Customize reviews description in product data tabs

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I would like to change the Default Text in the Reviews Product data tab.

I tried the following Code, it works for the descrption, but now are only the new descrption and nothing else is shown.
There are no Reviews, Stars or the option to leave an new Review.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_custom_description_tab', 98 ); 
function woo_custom_description_tab( $tabs ) { 


    $tabs['reviews']['callback'] = 'woo_custom_description_tab_content';    // Custom reviews callback 

    return $tabs; 
} 


function woo_custom_description_tab_content() { 
    echo '<h2>Custom Description</h2>'; 
    echo '<p>Here\'s a custom description</p>'; 
}
```

Has anybody a solution for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found an solution for me:

copy /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product-reviews.php

to your child-theme Folder and edit the comment_form Array.

I added the Key comment_notes_before with my custom description:

'comment_notes_before' => 'CUSTOM TEXT GOES HERE',

```
    $comment_form = array(
                    'title_reply'          => have_comments() ? __( 'Add a review', 'woocommerce' ) : sprintf( __( 'Be the first to review &ldquo;%s&rdquo;', 'woocommerce' ), get_the_title() ),
                    'title_reply_to'       => __( 'Leave a Reply to %s', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'comment_notes_after'  => '',
                    'comment_notes_before' => 'CUSTOM TEXT GOES HERE',
                    'fields'               => array(
                        'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author">' . '<label for="author">' . __( 'Name', 'woocommerce' ) . ' <span class="required">*</span></label> ' .
                                    '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30" aria-required="true" required /></p>',
                        'email'  => '<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">' . __( 'Email', 'woocommerce' ) . ' <span class="required">*</span></label> ' .
                                    '<input id="email" name="email" type="email" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30" aria-required="true" required /></p>',
                    ),
                    'label_submit'  => __( 'Submit', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'logged_in_as'  => '',
                    'comment_field' => ''
                );
```